# Get XML elements with a particular attribute value

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code to find xml elements that have a particular attribute value:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elems = 
    xmlDoc.Descendants("elemName")
    .Where(x => 
        x.Attribute("attrName").Value
        .Equals(
            filename,
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
        )
    );
```

The problem is that if the element does not have that attribute, according to the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx), it will return null and we'll get a crash when we try to do `null.Value`.

I've rewritten it like this:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elems = 
     xmlDoc.Descendants("elemName")
     .Where(x => 
         ((x.Attribute("attrName") == null) 
         ? "" 
         : x.Attribute("attrName").Value).Equals(
             filename,
             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
         )
     );
```

But I think it's a bit ugly. Is there an idiomatic way of doing this - I imagine this is a fairly common operation? I suppose I could just do a regular loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could use the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) for `x.Attribute("attrName").Value` and swap arguments of `String.Equals` to avoid the `NullReferenceException` as follows:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elems =
     xmlDoc.Descendants("elemName")
     .Where(x =>
         filename.Equals(
             x.Attribute("attrName")?.Value,
             StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
         )
     );
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a trick - you can cast [XAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to some data types: string, int, long, Guid, DateTime, bool etc and their nullable brothers. And if type supports `null` value there will be no NullReferenceException. You will simply get `null` as result:

```
(string)x.Attribute("attrName")
```

Next: I suggest you to use more meaningful names for variables, even if it's one-letter variable. I.e. instead of `x` for element you can use `e`.

And last, you can write following extension method to nicely compare strings

```
public static bool EqualsIgnoreCase(this string s, string value)
{
     return String.Equals(s, value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

And finally your parsing query will look like

```
from e in xmlDoc.Descendants("elemName")
where filename.EqualsIgnoreCase((string)e.Attribute("attrName"))
select e;
```